# AngularJS passing to directive heavy JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Well, i think i located the problem of chart not showing up, and the problem is probably that i'm loading heavy JSON object from RESTful server and passing it to directive where i'm generating chart but json is not still not downloaded completly.

JSON file is almost 1mb, which i'm getting in this way:

In Controller:

```
dataArchive.get().then(function(result){
    $scope.getData = result;
});
```

And HTML:

```
<divng-controller="archiveCtrl">
    <data-graph get-archive-data="getData"></data-graph>
</div>
```

And in directive:

```
var chart = function(data){
     var createchart = new AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
          //
     });
}

var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.$watch('data', function(){
        chart(scope.data);
    });
}

directives.directive('dataGraph', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            data: '=getArchiveData'
        },
        template: '<div id="chartdiv"></div>',
        link: linker
    };
});
```

Probably because of this, directive template will be created empty, and chart will not be generated.
How can i workaround this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correctly using `$watch` which should re-trigger the charting function, but I suggest you try a few other approaches to see which helps.

Firstly, the watch function will trigger on initial directive linking even if `data` is not there yet -- it will just return `undefined`, so the first time it will call the chart function with `undefined`, therefore, I imagine, rendering an empty chart. Then, when the data is downloaded, it will trigger `$watch` again, but perhaps your charting function will not work if called multiple times..? How about the following check:

```
scope.$watch('data', function(){
  if (!scope.data) return
  chart(scope.data);
});
```

Another approach which works for me when I need to wait for the resolution of some variable is using `$observe`, and not adding the variable into the scope of the directive:

```
<data-graph get-archive-data="{{ getData }}"></data-graph>

var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){
  attrs.$observe('getArchiveData', function(data){
    if (!data) return;
    chart(data);
  });
}

directives.directive('dataGraph', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    // Remove below  
    //scope: {
    //    data: '=getArchiveData'
    //},
    template: '<div id="chartdiv"></div>',
    link: linker
  };
});
```

Comment: Elisse, the problem is excactly as you described. I tried your solution but apparently, using observer funcion will crash chrome. Anyhow i got back to $watch method, where now i have passed json object to graph function sucessfuly, but even with json object, graph doesn't get created. I get empty directive template in DOM with no errors in console.

Comment: Well, if you can successfully see that your linker function actually has received the data, then I can only guess that the problem must be somewhere in your charting function. Another guess is that since you are specifying the chartdiv as your directive template, then there might be some sort of a race condition happening whereby the charting function can't find the element where to render the chart. Try hard-coding the chartdiv instead and see whether it works -- then you will know whether the problem is in the directive or charting function!

Comment: Yes, i thought the same thing and i hard-coded chart id, but same result. Yep, it's chart function. Strangly, in Chrome will be fired sometimes, sometimes not. Meanwhile in Firefox/Safari will not be fired at cleard cache, only if i reload the page. However chart function is written correctly, just doesn't get fired.

Comment: I'll make new question on function not firing. I really have no idea why is behaving like this. Thanks for help.

Comment: Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017787/angularjs-directive-not-firing-function/